# How to @autowired spring beans in JPOS QServer listener?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpos

We are running spring boot application. And within there we try to run JPOS QServer, after Spring is booted. It starts the Q2 and we can recive ISOmsgs from simulator clinet and we can response beck as well.

To start the Q2 we used xml configuration, which looks like this.

```
<server class="org.jpos.q2.iso.QServer" name="Server-A-Server" logger="Q2">

<attr name="port" type="java.lang.Integer">8118</attr>
<attr name="maxSessions" type="java.lang.Integer">100</attr>
<attr name="minSessions" type="java.lang.Integer">0</attr>

<!-- Format server name: "Project Name" + "-" + "Channel" -->
<channel name="Server-A-Channel" class="org.jpos.iso.channel.XMLChannel" logger="Q2"
         packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.XMLPackager">
</channel>

<request-listener class="fi.neocard.jpos.ISOMessageListener">
    <property name="timeout" value="10000"/>
</request-listener>
```

as you see from xml above it listens ISOMessangerListener class, which naturally not spring related class, Moreover I think that spring and QServer are running on different Servlets. So here it comes the problem that we do not have any Spring related beans in here and we cant @Autowired any. But our all business logic is already written in spring.

**What we tried so far**

1) Keep the application context static and use it whenever needed in ISOMessageListener (failed the context was null after receiving message to the listener).

2) To do something like this. `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);`

And readed a lot of articals how it is possible to get context from outside of spring.

So far I checked with `jvisualvm` that both Q2 and Springboot are running as a single application.

Hope to get at least some suggestions what to do.

Comment: Have you already checked [this](https://github.com/dgrandemange/spring-glue4jpos/wiki/Getting-started) out?

Comment: not really, gonna do it right away.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thanks for reference,  but seems to me that this is not really what I need, though not sure,  we are using spring boot and no xml configuration for it. For beans defined by annotations. When I am saying beans I am referring to Spring beans, not Qbeans.

Comment: How are you startng jpos? if you are starting as a standalone application, there is no way that spring objects are visible from jpos, or that jpos objects are visible int spring app.

You need to start Q2 from within Spring.

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PocketApplication.class, args);

        Q2 q2 = new Q2("src/main/resources/deploy/");
        q2.start();
    }`

This is the way how we do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone is interested here how I got it work, Instead of running ISOServer through Q2 (xml file) I just did it manually when my spring is already booted and then took the already existing bean of ISORequestListener and pass it to the server.

```
@Component
public class ISOserver implements ISORequestListener {

@Autowired
ISOserver isOserver;

@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
public void contextRefreshedEvent() throws Exception{
    Logger logger = new Logger();
    logger.addListener(new SimpleLogListener(System.out));
    ServerChannel channel = new XMLChannel(new XMLPackager());
    ((LogSource) channel).setLogger(logger, "channel");
    ISOServer isoServer = new ISOServer(8118, channel, null);
    isoServer.setLogger(logger, "server");
    isoServer.addISORequestListener(isOserver);
    new Thread(isoServer).start();
}

@Override
public boolean process(ISOSource isoSource, ISOMsg receivedISOmsg) {

    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, as I said in the jpos slack: I would start Q2 from within Spring, that's make the server more configurable, then you can change the packager, channel and add filters without need to recode and recompile,
not even restart the whole application